# Is there are general notion of uncertainty given an arbitrary probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, entropy

Consider the probability distribution $p(x)$. I am wondering if there is a general notion of uncertainty for $p(x)$. To provide some context, I am interested in ordering distributions based on uncertainty (i.e., $f(p(x)) \leq f(p(y))$ would imply the uncertainty in $p(x)$ is not greater than the uncertainty in $p(y)$) where $f$ is a mapping from a distribution to a real number that is a metric for quantifying uncertainty.

This seems difficult in general as uncertainty is ambiguous. Here is a simple example.

Let $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ be Gaussian, so $p(x) = \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $p(y) = \mathcal{N}(y|\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$. So, in this scenario, if I have $\sigma_x^2 \leq \sigma_y^2$, then I would consider $p(x)$ to have less uncertainty than $p(y)$.

However, even if extended to a multi-variate Gaussian (e.g., $p(\mathbf{x}| \mathbf{\mu}_x, \mathbf{\Sigma}_x)$ and $p(\mathbf{y}| \mathbf{\mu}_y, \mathbf{\Sigma}_y)$), the quantification is ambiguous as an ordering is required for covariance matrices (e.g., trace, determinant, or maximum eigenvalue are often used).

So, is there a general notion of uncertainty for probability distributions?

Comment: From your description uncertainty is essentially equivalent to variance.

Comment: @herbsteinberg That is correct. The pdf with less uncertainty is the pdf with a smaller standard error (in my description), which would I suppose correspond to the trace of the covariance matrix for a multi-variate Gaussian. However, I am wondering if a useful metric exists if the distribution is not a Gaussian or multi-variate Gaussian.

Comment: All distributions have variances (although some may be infinite).  Covariance matrices also exist in general.

Comment: The notion of stochastic dominance is an example of partial ordering on probability distributions. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general distributions a common measure of “uncertainty” comes from Information Theory: [the Maximum Entropy Distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution)

This measure has the advantage of a solid theoretical justification and produces distributions that make intuitive sense as “less informative”.